# Enhanced eCommerce, Single Page Application and Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, single-page-application

Our payment flow has just moved to a single page application, so we need to adjust how we're sending Enhanced eCommerce data to Google Analytics. We were receiving eCommerce data fine before the switch.

Our Google Analytics code is injected via Tag Manager, and we've made some attempts to send the funnel data using virtual page URLs but to no success yet.

What's the best way to go about implementing this?

Edit: We're currently trying to make the data available via the datalayer and are seeing it within the Tag Manager debugger, but it doesn't seem to be getting through to Google Analytics

Code below - the eCommerce data is sent at each stage of the funnel.

Step one:

`` window.dataLayer.push(window.GA_DATA_OBJECT_START);
ga('set', 'page', `/profile/?purchaseView=true&product=${this.state.product}`);
ga('send', 'pageview'); ``

Step two:

`` ga('set', 'page', `/profile/?billingConfirmed=true&product=${this.state.product}`);
ga('send', 'pageview'); ``

Step three:

`` window.dataLayer.push(window.GA_DATA_OBJECT_END);
ga('set', 'page', `/profile/?purchaseSuccess=true&product=${this.state.product}`);
ga('send', 'pageview'); ``

Comment: Which SPA frameworks are you using?

Comment: We are using react

Comment: Did you already taken a look to react-ga? 
https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga

Comment: If you are using GTM and pushing your Ecomm data to the dataLayer, then you shouldn't use the `send` method via onpage code (ie. `ga('send', 'pageview')`). This is because of the tracker names that GTM uses, which differs from the one GA uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its a single page application dont use send page view.

```
window.ga("ec:addProduct", {
                "id": product.id,                   // Product ID (string).
                "name": product.name, // Product name (string).
                "category": product.category,            // Product category (string).
                "brand": product.company,                // Product brand (string).
                "price": product.price,                 // Product price (currency).
                "quantity": 1
            });
            window.ga("ec:setAction", "remove");
            window.ga("send", "event", "enhanced booking", "leave page", "remove from booking");
```

another example

```
window.ga("ec:addProduct", {
                "id": booking._id,                   // Product ID (string).
                "name": booking.name, // Product name (string).
                "category": booking.services[0].category,            // Product category (string).
                "brand": booking.storeTitle,                // Product brand (string).
                "price": booking.price,                 // Product price (currency).
                "quantity": 1
            });
            window.ga("ec:setAction", "purchase", {          // Transaction details are provided in an actionFieldObject.
                "id": booking._id,                        // (Required) Transaction id (string).
                "revenue": booking.companyService.actualPrice,                     // Revenue (currency).
                "coupon": booking.coupon                  // Transaction coupon (string).
            });
            window.ga("send", "event", "Form", "Submit", "Booking Form");
```

use this only for impressions like

```
window.ga("ec:addImpression", {
    "id": companyId,                   // Product details are provided in an impressionFieldObject.
    "name": companyInfo.name,
    "category": companyInfo.category,
    "list": "Company Info"
});
window.ga("ec:setAction", "detail");
window.ga("send", "pageview");
```

Comment: is this preferable to making the data available via the datalayer? That's the approach we've been trying so far (sorry forgot to mention that in the original question, will amend)